# How to return list of unique words from file and sort them alphabetically

Tags: list, nltk, word-frequency

I've been trying to return list of unique words from file and sort them alphabetically by using NLTK but it didn't work although I've used several different approaches. Here is my code:

```
import nltk
from nltk import FreqDist

def get_vocabulary(self):
    with open(self.path, "r") as file:
        split = [line.split('\n') for line in file]
    fdist1 = FreqDist(split)
    unique_words = fdist1.hapaxes()
    return sorted(set(unique_words))
```

And the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Other similar approaches that I've tried also threw similar errors. The solution doesn't have to include nltk but I'd appreciate if you could show me where I made mistake(s) on my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

```
from collections import Counter
from nltk import word_tokenize

with open('filename.txt') as fin:
    word_count = Counter(word_tokenize(fin.read()))


# Sorted by most common.
word_count.most_common()

# Sorted alphabetically
sorted(word_count.items())

# If you just need the words. 
sorted(word_count)
```

Comment: It's not working. I need the unique words like ['albanologie', 'allgemeine', 'als'] but what I get with your code is [('(', 2), (')', 2), ('Albanologie', 1)]